# Postfix can send mail from local server and iphone but cannot receive any

Tags: postfix-mta

So I'm trying to set up a mail server with a blocked port 25. So im now trying to use port 587. I manged to get sending email working but, I cant recive any mail. I'm using dynu Outbound SMTP Relay and now im trying to use their Email Store/Forward service to forward me all mail to port 587. I can even send mail from my iphone through my mail server so its not just localy i can send mail. When i can send mail from my iphone the port 587 have to be open? So i dont understand why i cant recive any.

On their site its a warning like this: Warning! Hostname mail.rajonan.no cannot be reached on port 587!

```
My master.cf: https://pastebin.com/GtAs52hM
My main.cf: https://pastebin.com/PA0HsMXr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mail.rajonan.no doesn't appear to exist in public DNS.
If the server cannot be found connection to port 587 will never succeed.

so, it looks like you have a typo!

mail.rajohan.no does not respond on port 587 either, however
 - which - if it is the correct fqdn - suggests you have either a firewall rule / NAT problem, 
or need to take a closer look at your **smtpd** settings.